# Python versions mixed up. Requesting a specific version starts an unexpected version

Tags: python, centos

I have Python 2.4 and 2.7 on my Centos server.
When I execute python I get version 2.7 srat up.
When I execute python2.4 I get version 2.4 start up.
The above is as I want but when I execute python2.7 I get python2.4 start up.
I want to put this right but can't work out how.
I was expecting to see a link from 2.7 to 2.4 but all I can find is as follows:

In /usr/bin directory I have:

```
python  
python2 -> python
python2.4
```

In /usr/local/bin I have:

```
python
python2.7
python2.7-config
python-config -> python2.7-config
```

I've had a look in python2.7-config but can see nothing that may link the python2.7 bin to python2.4.
Can anyone suggest how I might correct this issue. I don't want to start uninstalling python versions as I know (from bitter experience) that that can mess up the OS.
Thanks

--edit--

```
/usr/bin/python --- 2.4
/usr/bin/python2 --- 2.4
/usr/bin/python2.4 --- 2.4
/usr/local/bin/python --- 2.7
/usr/local/bin/python2.7 --- 2.4
```

Comment: what does `which python2.7` show?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Try removing `python` from both /usr/bin/ and /usr/local/bin/ as well 
   as removing `python2` from /usr/bin/.
2. Then try running `which python2.7` to see, where does `python2.7`    comes from.
3. Finally, create a single `python` and a single `python2` symlinks for    desired python versions in /usr/bin/. Note, that CentOS may rely on `python ->    python2.4` and `python2 -> python2.4` links.

Comment: I've editied the post to show what versins the various python files are. It's all got a bit confusing. I've removed (moved actually) python2.7 that is completely misleading. I haven't deleted any of the other pythons as I don't want to mess anything up. Getting rid of the bogus 2.7 python will prevent confusion in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that I understood you completely.
Try adding a shebang to your scripts stating the python version to use:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7
```

you can also debug from your scripts by printing the python version the script is using:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.version
```